# Tree Parent child hierarchy Hiding

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to implement tree widget but it doesn't have to show the hierarchy line.
Please help on this.

[image: Tree view]

(Hierarchy means the line between parent and child.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use QSS styles - assign empty image to lines...

```
QTreeView::branch
 {
    border-image: none;
    image: url(:/style/blankImage.png);
 }
```

if lines are still exists after that- create png with one transparent pixel and assign it to TreeView's branch, i haven't checked variant with no image at all.